# Vapor Swift Client for a Message Queue / RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, message-queue, vapor

I'm having a play with Swift Vapor and want to build a web API using microservices.

What's the best way for sending messages between microservices built with Vapor and a message queue such as RabbitMQ?

Comment: Hi Adam, do you found any RabbitMQ framework for Swift?

Comment: No, I gave up. I was trying to use https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Kafka but it didn't have a High Level Consumer. I did create by own, but never got it working in a docker container.

Answer (score 2):

The option right now I think is Redis Pub/Sub which there are a Vapor package for.

We have done a little work on a Kafka package but it never got finished. Besides this we can see what the new Server Side Swift working group comes up with. They have Kafka on their list, and I have personally suggested RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

I just got aware of this package, looks like it could do what you want :) https://github.com/johnbona/disque

Comment: Does this support listening for messages are a particular queue? Can't see in the docs how you might do this? Don't want to be polling the message queue to see if there are new messages